# jQuery datePicker not respecting date format

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have set up a datepicker in a form using the following js:

```
$("#Expiry").datepicker({
   regional: 'en-GB',
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
   firstDay: 1
});
```

and have the following in my view (asp.net MVC)

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Expiry) %>
```

In my model, Expiry is a nullable `DateTime?`

When I use the datepicker to choose a date it does so with the correct format

When I load data from the database it always displays with 00:00:00 at the end for the time portion

How can I get it to not do this?

If I try to use a formatting expression in my binding then it won't compile.

Surely jQuery should respect the formatting I've specified for values that are pre-loaded into the form field?

It does apply the datepicker to the field, so I can choose with a calendar. It just doesn't apply the formatting to the loaded value

any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't `$("Expiry")` be `$("#Expiry")`?

Comment: corrected - I thought the editor here added an 'S' which I deleted before posting- maybe it was some markdown or something? anyway - now corrected

Comment: I faced the same problem. What i did was extract the date part using javascript's `dateVal.substr(0,10)` and set it when binding the `textbox` to the `datepicker`. Not an elegant solution, but got the job done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I get it to not do this?

You could decorate the corresponding `DateTime` property on your view model with the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute which allows you to specify a format:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? Expiry { get; set; }

    ... other properties
}
```

and inside the view replace the `TextBoxFor` with an `EditorFor` call:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.Expiry) %>
```

Comment: I get the same behaviour with those changes applied - i.e. 00:00:00 is still displayed

Comment: Ooops my bad, forgot `ApplyFormatInEditMode=true` :-) If you don't use this it will work with DisplayFor but not with EditorFor. Sorry. Should be fine now.

Comment: Hey guys, I think I´m kinda close here, but don´t get it to work. I have this in the view   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { @class = "datepicker" }) and the model´s data value shows ok, but the datepicker class is not applied, therefor, I can not change the date and the style is ugly. If I change it to TextBoxFor, datepciker works but format is not applied. any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Create an editor template `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml` with following content:

```
@model DateTime?
@{
string finalDate = string.Empty;

if (Model != null)
{
    DateTime date = (DateTime)Model;
    finalDate = String.Format("{0:d}", date.Date.ToShortDateString());
}

@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, finalDate, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

In your View write (sorry it's razor syntax, I don't know the aspx syntax)

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Expiry)
```

So in future, you don't have to worry about date format in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is going to have only one culture, you could set the culture in the web.config file like this:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" />
```

or for Spain:

```
<globalization culture="es-ES" />
```

This way, the binding will consider the specified format to convert the form input value.